# MySql match against order by relevance, and another column

Tags: mysql, sql, match-against

I want to order a `match against` search by relevance, and then by a `listing_time` column. The relevance search works great, but when I add the listing_time column the search is bringing what looks like random results.

This is my `sql`:

```
SELECT title, listing_time, match(description) against('+clip' in boolean mode) as rel
FROM product order by rel desc
```

This brings 86 results in 0.2 seconds and all the results have `relevance 1`. Great.

But when I try the same search with the additional cloumn

```
FROM product order by rel, listing_time desc
```

I get 1000 results in 27 seconds and their relevance is all over the place. Awful.

So how do I do this correctly? I want the relevant results and I want them ordered by listing_time.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you intend for the `order by` to be:

```
order by rel desc, listing_time desc
-------------^
```

`asc` and `desc` apply to each key.

Nothing in your question suggests that the two result sets would be different, such I am guessing the queries are not exactly the same (say, because of a `join` or `where` clause).

Comment: It could also be a `TOP X` or `FETCH FIRST X ROWS ONLY` or `LIMIT X` would give different results with just a change in order.

Comment: @Hogan . . . MySQL supports neither of those constructs.  The version used in MySQL is `limit` and would be after the `order by` clause.

Comment: The suggestion doesn't change the result. And it's the same query other than changing rel desc to rel desc, listing_time desc.